# What is a word or a phrase for "finding balance"?

Tags: synonyms

I want a stoic and blissful name for my blog, and unfortunately "finding balance" is not available. Can you suggest something along the lines of that? I basically want this to be about how my life is a balancing act between trying and wanting to be different things at once.

Comment: Balancing act..

Answer (score 1):

How about something like, "Locating Stasis", or "Achieving Equilibrium".

Answer (score 0):

What about "Spirit Level"? That's all about balance, it's quite concrete -- but the first word could be a play on words to denote your inner well-being (or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

'Achieving Stability'

'Juggling Safely'

'Busily Composed'